# Why do my DispatcherServlet config not work in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to determine whether  he has rights to access the url or not.But I want to give all the css,js can be accessed.So I config the web.xml like this:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-  class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

    <mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <bean class="com.test.web.interceptor.MyInterceptor">
            <property name="loginUrl">
                <value>http://localhost:8080/my-web/login.jsp</value>                   
            </property> 
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

and set spring-servlet.xml like this:

```
  <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
  <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
```

and MyInterceptor like this:

```
public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1,
        Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    StringBuffer currentUrl = request.getRequestURL(); 
    String path = request.getServletPath(); 
     if(path.matches( "(.*/((css)|(js)|(images)).*)"
    )){
        System.out.println(path);
        return true;
    }
     //check token,if null return to login.jsp

  }
```

After this,I think that the css and js request can be accessed and not go to my interceptors.BUt it is wrong.Now I have two questions:

1. I have set the `mvc:resources`,the book say that it will not be processed by DispatcherServlet,Why do the css or js url request still go to MyInterceptor?
2. I visit the index.jsp page,in MyInterceptor I can get the css request,js request,but Why do I not get the jsp page request?

Comment: Probably the location that you have given in mvc:resources is incorrect.
It is generally, js/css , kept inside resources folder.
And then it is like <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

Comment: @KuldeepSChauhan,You say if I set the mvc:resources correctly,it must not go to the HandlerInterceptor ?

Comment: I see the book write like  <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />,but I also seach the other way like this:<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/,/css/" />,Can you tell me what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, that would be skipped by the Spring MVC. Further, anything that is inside the WEB-INF folder cannot be accessed directly. So all your css and js files should be placed out of it. I gave example of these resources's  location as per more generally used 'Maven' projects.